# Double-hop issue with WCF Service and Sharepoint Service both hosted on same iis server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am getting the below exception when a WCF  service is trying to access a sharepoint site for content.

```
Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6592536
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +55

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10733331
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
```

My IIS server version is IIS 8.0.
Our Sharepoint Server/Site is on the same domain as my client computer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the loopback check: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en-us